# why there's confilct between two jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with two radio options and a submit button. Depending on which radio button is selected when the submit button is pressed, I want a different calculating function to be called.

```
     <input type="radio" name="frm" id="airradio1"  onclick="setairform1()">&nbsp; Enter individual flights(more accurate) <br>
    <input type="radio" name="frm" id="airradio2" onclick="setairform2()">&nbsp; Enter numbers of flight(faster)<br>

    <div><button type="button" id="aircalc" >calculate</button></div>
```

My calculation functions work well. But, when I select the second radio button and then click the calc button, it will show the result of the last calculation I made using the first method.

Here is my Javascript/jQuery, what am I doing wrong?

```
        $("#airradio2").click(function(){
                $("#aircalc").click(myairFunction2);


            });


        $("#airradio1").click(function(){
            $("#aircalc").click(function(){
                $("#airanswer").val("");
                var dept = $("#dept").val();
                var dest = $("#dest").val();
                $.post('airtravel.php',{dept: dept, dest: dest}, function(data){
                    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    var a =response.co2;
                    var mile = (response.miles).toFixed(4);
                    var numpass = $("#numpass").val();
                    var flightclass = $("#flightclass").val();
                    var trip = $("input[name='trip']:checked").val();
                    var total = (a * trip * flightclass * numpass).toFixed(4);

                    var sum = "<div>Trip from " + dept + " to " + dest + ", you traveled " + mile + "miles</div>";
                    $("#airanswer").text(total);
                    $("#results").append(sum);

                });


            });

        });
```

Comment: You're binding two `.click()` events to `$('#aircalc')`...

Comment: The OP is binding a new click() function every time one of the radios is clicked.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Precisely. The OP is not removing the previous event handler though, so ***all*** event handlers will fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding two `.click()` events to `$('#aircalc')`. To prevent double binding, consider binding with [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) so that you can remove the previous handler each time using [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/).

```
$("#airradio2").on('click', function() {
    $("#aircalc").off('click').on('click', myairFunction2);
});


$("#airradio1").on('click', function() {
    $("#aircalc").off('click').on('click', function() {
        $("#airanswer").val("");
        var dept = $("#dept").val();
        var dest = $("#dest").val();
        $.post('airtravel.php',{dept: dept, dest: dest}, function(data) {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            var a =response.co2;
            var mile = (response.miles).toFixed(4);
            var numpass = $("#numpass").val();
            var flightclass = $("#flightclass").val();
            var trip = $("input[name='trip']:checked").val();
            var total = (a * trip * flightclass * numpass).toFixed(4);
            var sum = "<div>Trip from " + dept + " to " 
                + dest + ", you traveled " + mile + "miles</div>";
            $("#airanswer").text(total);
            $("#results").append(sum);
        });
    });
});
```

An alternative and a much better way of doing it, would be to identify which radio button is selected and call the appropriate function (as pointed out by @GriffeyDog):

```
// Save off objects to prevent DOM re-traversal
var $dept = $('#dept'),
    $dest = $('#dest');

$('#aircalc').on('click', function () {
    if($('#airradio1').is(':checked')) {
        $("#airanswer").val("");
        $.post('airtravel.php',{dept: $dept.val(), dest: $dest.val()}, function(data) {
            var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            var a =response.co2;
            var mile = (response.miles).toFixed(4);
            var numpass = $("#numpass").val();
            var flightclass = $("#flightclass").val();
            var trip = $("input[name='trip']:checked").val();
            var total = (a * trip * flightclass * numpass).toFixed(4);
            var sum = "<div>Trip from " + dept + " to " 
            + dest + ", you traveled " + mile + "miles</div>";
            $("#airanswer").text(total);
            $("#results").append(sum);
        });
    } else {
        myairFunction2();
    }
});
```

Comment: Or just have one click handler on `aircalc` that simply checks which of the two radios is selected.

Comment: @GriffeyDog Yep. I was working on that edit as well. I cited your common and added it to my answer.

Comment: Good answer, +1. <Filling space>